# decltype parenthesis syntax for a lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, decltype

I'm trying to have a better understanding of ***decltype*** to determine the type of an expression at compile-time. Let's say for example I do it with a double variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main(){
    double a;
    typedef decltype(a) a_type;
    typedef decltype((a)) ref_a_type;
    typedef decltype(a)& o_ref_a_type;

    a_type b;
    ref_a_type c = b;
    o_ref_a_type d = b;

  if (std::is_same<decltype(b), double>::value) std::cout << "b is double\n";
  if (std::is_same<decltype(c), double&>::value) std::cout << "c is double&\n";
  if (std::is_same<decltype(d), double&>::value) std::cout << "d is double&\n";
}
```

If I have understood correctly these points should be true:

1. `decltype(a)` returns `double&` if `a` is a lvalue and `double` otherwise.
2. decltype deduces the type of an expression, unless it is applied to a variable, in which case it deduces the type of that variable.
3. If the variable is parenthesized, it becomes an lvalue expression.

Thus, `decltype((a))` and `decltype(a)&` are equivalent in this case, but not always equivalent, for example, if `a` is not a variable:

```
typedef decltype((5)) ref_a_type;
typedef decltype(5)& o_ref_a_type;
```

then both types are not equivalent (`ref_a_type` is `int` and `o_ref_a_type` is `int&`, since the extra parenthesis are useless in this case). Can someone give a better explanation of this? Should I use the first or the second way?
IMO it seems more readable and understandable the second way than the first.

Comment: If `T` is a non-reference type, then `decltype(f())` is `T`, `T&`, `T&&` respectively for `T f();`, `T& f();`, `T&& f();`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules for `decltype(e)` are, as far as the C++ standard goes, pretty clear, so I'll just copy them (from [dcl.type.simple]):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
> (4.1) — if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)`
> is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions,
> the program is ill-formed;
> (4.2) — otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> (4.3) — otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of e;
> (4.4) — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

So going through your examples in order:

1. `decltype(a)`: `a` is an unparenthesized *id-expression*, so this is just the type of `a`: `double`.
2. `decltype((a))`: now it's parenthesized, so we skip the first bullet. `a` isn't an xvalue, it's an lvalue, so this is `double&`.
3. `decltype(a)&`: this is just the first case again, so it's `double&`.
4. `decltype((5))`: this is neither an *id-expression* (parenthesized or otherwise), an xvalue, or an lvalue - it's a prvalue, so we drop to the last bullet to just get the type of the expression: `int`.
5. `decltype(5)&`: same as the last point, except now you're explicitly adding a `&`, so `int&`.

> Should I use the first or the second way?

It depends on what type you actually want to get. The two ways mean different things - you should use whichever one solves the direct problem you're trying to solve.

More generally, `decltype(expr)&` is *always* an lvalue reference due to reference collapsing rules.

`decltype((expr))` could be a non-reference prvalue (as with `decltype((5))`), an lvalue reference (as with `decltype((a))`), or an rvalue reference (as with `decltype((std::move(a)))`).